# Trigger GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged event in pageload if session is == to column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to use selectedindex on my gridview if it has a column with an == value to session.

Right now I am only successfull on changing its background color. But how could I also trigger the button If it has similar value on my Session.

```
   private void load_session_value()
    {
        string trans_id = Session["transaction_id_report"].ToString();
        string trans_number = Session["transaction_no_report"].ToString();

        //string grid_value_id = GridView1
        //string grid_value_num
        if (trans_id != null && trans_number != null)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Text.ToString() == trans_id && row.Cells[2].Text.ToString() == trans_number)
                {
                    row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");

                    GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(),new EventArgs());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my current output during `page_load`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but i think you are looking for this.

```
if (row.Cells[1].Text.ToString() == trans_id && row.Cells[2].Text.ToString() == trans_number)
{
    row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");

    //call the Button1_Click method
    Button1_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do the button click stuff
}
```

Comment: Something like that.But if the session is similar to a value inside my gridview I wanted to automatically trigger the `protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` during page_load. Right now I'm successfull on changing its color.

Comment: What does `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` do exactly? Maybe it could be solved in another way.

Comment: I made some progress now thanks to your code. I just added this ` GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(),new EventArgs());` now I need to use GridView1.SelectedIndex on a row that has the same value on my session.